# Is `Thread.checkAccess()` the appropriate replacement for `Thread.suspend()`?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, deprecated, suspend

IntelliJ suggests that I replace the deprecated `Thread.suspend()` with `Thread.checkAccess()`. Based on [the (very brief) documents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#checkAccess()), `checkAccess()` seems like a good idea, but also seems quite different than `.suspend()`, which certainly seems [**very** bad based on the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html). Yet those same docs don't seem to offer a useful alternative to `.suspend()`, except to suggest that each solution presented has some non-trivial drawbacks.

At the same time, while much better, it seems `.checkAccess()` relies on there being a SecurityManager implemented, so simply clicking "fix this" also seems like a bad idea without some well-thought-out implementation.

I have made the suggested change, and nothing has broken – yet... But I wonder...

If `.checkAccess()` is the best alternative, what is the best way to implement it in a nutshell? If it isn't, what is a better alternative?

Comment: Looking at the docs/source, `suspend()` first calls `checkAccess()`; so, perhaps it's simply suggesting `checkAccess()` is the "useful" bit of the `suspend()` call...?

Comment: The real question is why you need to use `suspend()` anyway: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: ^ that is the real question. It looks like an attempt to create a non-blocking function in a very old code base with what was available at the time. Going for a kaizen approach, I'm making just the minimal changes for now to at least remove deprecations.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs of `Thread.suspend`:

> First, the checkAccess method of this thread is called with no arguments. This may result in throwing a SecurityException (in the current thread).
>
> If the thread is alive, it is suspended and makes no further progress unless and until it is resumed.

So, invoking `checkAccess()` is preserving the "safe" part of the `suspend()` call, in that it will throw an exception if you don't have access, but it won't then proceed to the dangerous deadlocking operation.

I don't precisely know what "suspend" does - I have never used this method, and it is helpfully defined as "Suspends this thread". But if you simply want to wait for something to happen, you could wait on some object:

```
synchronized (thing) {
  thing.wait();
}
```

then call `thing.notify()` from the thread you would otherwise be using to resume the thread.

---

But note that the primitive synchronization methods on `Object` are inherently difficult to use - for example, `Object.wait()` may spuriously wake up. You should *rarely* be using them directly (or `Thread`, for that matter).

There is a bunch of higher-level synchronization objects in the `java.util.concurrent` package. For example, you could have a queue shared between your "suspended" and "resuming" threads, where, at the point you want to suspend, one thread waits for the other to put something into the queue.

Comment: I think this answer gets me close to where I want, thank you. For the communities' sake, I'll wait a day or so before accepting it.